# My jsp page is not displaying the updated values from database after refreshing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, refresh

In my java web application I used servlets(controller) and jsp(view) and POJO classes.I am running my application for every 10 seconds and storing the updated values into database.And in my servlet I am fetching those values and forwarding to jsp that will display updated values.
I used
    `response.setHeader("Refresh","10;url="+request.getContextPath+"/SiteAvailabilityServlet");`

Here my jsp looks like: In the top frame I have drop down list.I select one url and clicks submit button.And the updated values should be displayed in bottom frame.
In my SiteAvailabilityServlet I am getting the selected url as
       `request.getParameter("urlsel");` giving me the correct selected url in jsp(browser)..
But when it call above `response.setHeader(----);` for refreshing it is taking the `urlsel` as `null` and not displaying updated values. How to solve this problem? Please help me. Even If I use html meta tag it is taking `null` value from drop down list.Please help me.